# Using a recursive method instead of a while loop

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on a project for a Java 2 class which has to show population growth of organisms for a period of days inputted by the user. I was able to implement the method using a while loop, but am having difficulty converting it to a recursive method.

```
while(day <= totalDays)
{
    if (day == 1){
        System.out.println(organs);
        day++; //day one there is no increase
    }
    else{
        organs = organs + organs*(increase/100); //add % increase of organisms
        System.out.println(organs);
        day++;}
}
```

Here is my unsuccessful attempt at a recursive method so far.

```
public static double showPopulation(int dayNum, int days, double organisms, 
        double dailyIncrease)
{
    if(dayNum == totalDays)
    {
        return organisms + (organisms*dailyIncrease);
    }
    else
        return showPopulation(dayNum+1, days, organisms, dailyIncrease) + organisms*dailyIncrease;
```

Comment: Why do you need recursion if you've got a perfectly valid iterative solution?

Comment: Recursion makes sense in 2 cases: when it really helps to make code shorter and clearer or where the task itself has recursive nature.

Comment: ... or when you're working in Erlang and don't have any choice :)

Comment: I'm required to show both working methods for the project (iterative and recursive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public int population(int days, int startingOrganisms, double dailyIncrease) {
      if (days <= 1) {
         System.out.print(days + " " + startingOrganisms);
         //no increase, finish condition
         return startingOrganisms;
      } else {
         // we need to find the population of yesterday to know how much organisms exist today
         int populationYesterday = population(days - 1, startingOrganisms, dailyIncrease);
         int populationToday = populationYesterday + (populationYesterday * dailyIncrease / 100);

         System.out.print(days + " " + populationToday);
         return populationToday;
      }
   }
```

And then just invoke it and print the result

```
System.out.println( population(10, 1000, 30.2);
```

Do you need to print the growth each each step of the way?

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to add that right now. Needs to be in the form of dayNumber \t\t population.

Comment: @Kurter21 I added some prints that could help you achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Call the following function by `showPopulation(totalDays, organ, dailyIncrease)`. Here I am assuming `totalDays` is the entire number of days, `organ` is the initial value of the "organs", and `dailyIncrease` is a percentage.

```
public static double showPopulation(int dayNum, double organ, double dailyIncrease) {
    if(dayNum <= 1) {
        return organ;
    } else {
        return (1 + dailyIncrease) * showPopulation(dayNum - 1, organ, dailyIncrease);
    }
}
```

Generally, when using iteration we usually start from the base case. In terms of this question, it means day 1, or when `dayNum == 1`. Whereas when applying recursion, we usually start considering the problem from the final state of the procedures. In this problem, it means the last day (`totalDays`).

Answer (score 0):

While I guess thisis for Homework, here is how it should work

```
public static double showPopulation(int dayNum, double organisms, 
        double dailyIncrease)
{
    if(dayNum == 1)
    {
        return organisms + (organisms*dailyIncrease);
    }else{
        return showPopulation(dayNum-1, organisms, dailyIncrease) + organisms*dailyIncrease;
    }
}
```

I did not run it, so beware of further bugs.

You forgot the termination condition. It must always get a step closer to this condition, usually by decreasing until reaching 0 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code:**

```
public static double showPopulation(int totalDay,int days, double organisms, 
            double dailyIncrease)  {
        if(days == totalDay) {
            return organisms;
        }
        else{
            organisms+=organisms*dailyIncrease;
            return showPopulation(totalDay,++days, organisms, dailyIncrease);
        }

    }
```